# Spring MVC/Hibernate - NullValueInNestedPathException, Invalid property, value of nested property is null?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

We are currently enhancing an *already existing* web application in Spring MVC (and I'm just learning the framework). I tried adding another property to an object that is being pushed into a database (I added the corresponding column, too) but I keep getting the `NullValueInNestedPathException` error.

I already tried Google and the suggestions were as follows:

1) explicitly declare the constructor for the new property (tried, didn't solve it)
2) make sure you instantiate the new object (tried, didn't solve it)
3) double check getters/setters of the property (they were OK, wasn't the error)
4) create a serialVersionUID (nah!)
5) use debug feature (I did, and I found out that the property *is* null)

Please help! T.T Here are the codes:

VO of the new property:

```
public class ShiftAssignmentLookupVO implements Serializable{

    ...
    public ShiftAssignmentLookupVO(){}

    public String getShiftAssignmentStringValue(){
     return shiftAssignmentStringValue;
    }
    public void setShiftAssignmentStringValue(String shiftAssignmentStringValue){
     this.shiftAssignmentStringValue = shiftAssignmentStringValue;
    }
    ...
}
```

VO of the object that contains the property:

```
public class EmployeeCalendarVO implements Serializable {
    ...
    //the new property:
    private ShiftAssignmentLookupVO shiftAssignmentVO = new ShiftAssignmentLookupVO();

    public void setShiftAssignmentVO(ShiftAssignmentLookupVO shiftAssignmentVO){
      this.shiftAssignmentVO = shiftAssignmentVO;
    }
    public ShiftAssignmentLookupVO getShiftAssignmentVO(){
      return shiftAssignmentVO;
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is the hibernate mapping:

```
<class name = "EmployeeCalendarVO" table = "EMP_WRK_CDR">
    ...
    <many-to-one name = "shiftAssignmentVO" lazy = "false">
        <column name = "ID_ASSIGNMENT" />
    </many-to-one>
    ...
</class>
```

The jsp where I try to access the property:

```
<spring:bind path = "employeecalendar.empCalList[${ecl.index}].shiftAssignmentVO.shiftAssignmentID">
   ...
</spring:bind>
```

And last (whew!) the stack trace:

```
Aug 8, 2013 10:36:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dtr threw exception
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property     'empCalList[0].shiftAssignmentVO' of bean class     [com.safeway.dtr.employee.vo.EmpCalManager]: Value of nested property     'empCalList[0].shiftAssignmentVO' is null
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:443)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:418)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:524)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:78)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:337)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag.doStartTagInternal(BindTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.employee.employeecalendar_jsp._jspService(employeecalendar_jsp.java:1184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:624)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:149)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:761)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:893)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.defaultLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f1(defaultLayout_jsp.java:286)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.defaultLayout_jsp._jspService(defaultLayout_jsp.java:115)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:880)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Hi drurenia, here is the empCalManager as requested:

```
public class EmpCalManager {  
    ...
    private List<EmployeeCalendarVO> empCalList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<EmployeeCalendarVO>(),FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(EmployeeCalendarVO.class));
    public List<EmployeeCalendarVO> getEmpCalList() {
        return empCalList;
    }
    public void setEmpCalList(List<EmployeeCalendarVO> empCalList) {
        this.empCalList = empCalList;
    }
    ...
}
```

This piece pulls from the table:

```
public List<EmployeeCalendarVO> getEmployeeWorkCalendar(int empId, Date from, Date to){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.flush();
    Query query = session.createQuery(" from EmployeeCalendarVO as empWrkCdr where " +
            "empWrkCdr.employeeId = ? AND empWrkCdr.workDate between ? AND ? order by empWrkCdr.workDate");

    query.setInteger(0, empId);

    query.setDate(1, from);
    query.setDate(2, to);

    return query.list();
}
```

Any ideas? Suggestions? **Thanks to anyone who will help!**
*PS if some codes/part of codes that are missing in this post, kindly inform me so I can post them.

Comment: Are you getting your shifts from your database somewhere?

Comment: Yes but the code for that just returns _whole_ rows from my table. I will post the DAO implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong: It seems that I set the default value of the column for the new property to `null`! I hope that others that are getting this same error try this solution out. -__-! Thanks to `drurenia` taking some interest! :D